# Assigning Labels to card, when draged to list

Tags: trello, trello-labels

Let's say on a board we have two lists. List `A` and `B`. Whenever a item get's dragged from any list to list `B`, I'd like it to be assigned a specific label (and removed others if they are set).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the third-party automation tool [Butler for Trello](https://butlerfortrello.com) to do the job for you.

- Log on to the [Butler for Trello dashboard](https://butlerfortrello.com/dashboard.html)
- Invite Butler to your Board

[image: Invite Butler]

- Click Edit Board to create a command

[image: Edit Board]

- Use the *Triggers* and *Actions* panel to enter your command

  - `when a card is added to list "B", remove all the labels from the card, and add the "Specific" label to the card`
- Test to make sure it works, and you're off to the races

Here's how it looks in action

[image: Trello Remove Labels and Add New]